# launching iphone app in itunes store help

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

I developed an iPhone app using UITablesView and database in the background.
I want to know furthur step for it like after completing the app development how to proceed furthur for launching it in itunes store.
Can anyone help me in detail about it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for the [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/) and you can submit your apps to the App Store through that.